# Como usar los totales de una tabla dinámica en un dashboard

Tags: excel, tabla-dinámica

Me gustaría meter los totales de una tabla dinámica en una especie de Dashboard pero cuando pongo nombre a la celda donde se muestran los totales. Por ejmplo a la J63 le llamo "TotalPedidos" y luego en una celda cualquyiera pongo la formula ='TotalPedidos' todo va bien hasta que actualizo los datos y la TD tiene mas filas y ahora el total está en la celda J73 por ejmplo y pierdo el valor rela en el dashboard.

[image: TD]

No se si se puede fijar esto de alguna manera.

De hecho tampoco se como anular el nombre de la celda ahora que ya no es el verdadero total, ese nombre se queda ahi para siempre?

Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener datos de totales de una tabla dinámica dispones de la [función](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/importardatosdinamicos-funci%C3%B3n-importardatosdinamicos-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f) `IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS`

Necesitas saber el nombre de la medida y una referencia a una celda (cualquiera) donde se ubique la tabla dinámica. Poe ejemplo

```
= IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS("Pedidos", J6)
```

Para cambiar o eliminar un nombre de celda personalizado:

- Presiona las teclas Control + F3 o ingresa a la ficha Fórmulas, ubica el grupo Nombres definidos y haz clic en el comando Administrador de nombres.
- En la ventana Administrador de nombres, elije el nombre que quieras cambiar y haz clic en el botón Modificar o Eliminar.

Comment: Gracias pero no logro hacer funcionar IMPORTARDATOS. Los campos de la Tabla dinámica se llaman "Pedido", "Gastado" y "facturado" y cuando intento esto =IMPORTARDATOS("Pedido"; J6) Me sale #!REF! continuamete

Comment: Primero, la función es `IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS` y no  `IMPORTARDATOS`, segundo, la referencia `J6` es un ejemplo, debe ser una referencia válida a una celda de tu tabla dinámica, por último, si tienes dudas sobre la función, en la respuesta tienes un enlace a la documentación.

Answer (score 1):

Al final y sguiendo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIbwmk76g1w&ab_channel=WalterC%C3%B3rdova  lo que he hecho es simplemente en la barra de forulas poner = y seleccionar la celda cn el total y el ya me pone automáticamente la formula

=IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS("[Measures].[Suma de Importe neto 2]";$I$3)

Un saludo